# SQL Server increment and return value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is there anything like a prefix/postfix increment operator in SQL or a way to simulate it's behavior? Ideally I could do something like:

```
declare @count int = 0

cast(@count++ as varchar)
```

The desired output would be '0' and one greater each time thereafter.

Here's a simple representation of my problem.

```
select
    case when x is not null then cast(@count++ as varchar) + ' more text' else '' end +
    case when y is not null then cast(@count++ as varchar) + ' more text' else '' end +
    case when z is not null then cast(@count++ as varchar) + ' more text' else '' end +
    --and so on
```

Regardless of which columns are `null`, I need to display 0, 1, 2, 3... etc.

Comment: `set @count = @count + 1` ?

Comment: Something like this 

SELECT 0 - 1 +ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS Row from table1

Comment: @acfrancis Does the assignment but returns nothing (that I'm aware of). What would be cast?

Comment: So you are looking for a single statement that both increments the variable and returns a value?

Comment: @MartinSmith Exactly, yes. Many programming languages offer this feature, wasn't sure if I could accomplish the same in SQL.

Comment: If you *need* it to be a single statement, my idea won't work. Do you really need it or is it a nice to have?

Comment: @acfrancis It would be convenient for the problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: Then I think Martin Smith's sequence is the way to go. Interesting problem to have. Care to expand on it?

Comment: @acfrancis So the problem is that I'm in a case statement. I have to somehow increment and cast within.

Comment: Why do you have this requirement? What is the end goal?

Comment: @MartinSmith I've updated with exactly what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: I wish I hadn't asked :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the question in the comments. You can use something like

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Ord) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' more text '
        FROM   (VALUES (1,low),
                       (2,high),
                       (3,number)) V(Ord, Col)
        WHERE  Col IS NOT NULL
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','varchar(max)') AS txt
FROM   master..spt_values
```

Regarding the question in the question. It's not possible with variables on their own

My first thought would be to use a sequence instead though.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE S START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 ;
GO

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR S; -- Increments and returns value

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR S; -- Increments and returns value
```

Quite a hacky way to do something similar with variables would be to pass it through a dummy table with a single row. Though the use of variables could easily be removed from this example in lieu of simply using the single row's column value as the counter directly.

```
/*Setup*/

DECLARE @T TABLE(X INT);

INSERT INTO @T DEFAULT VALUES;   

DECLARE @Counter INT = 0;

/*Increment variable and return result*/    
UPDATE @T SET @Counter = X = @Counter + 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.X

/*Increment variable and return result*/
UPDATE @T SET @Counter = X = @Counter + 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.X
```

Comment: And as a prefix operator `UPDATE @T SET @Counter += 1 OUTPUT @Counter` seems to work. Not sure that behaviour is guaranteed anywhere though.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I'm in transit, I'll check this out in just a few.

Comment: So this absolutely works in general, and answers my question (+1). I left out some context though that I'm actually doing this in a case statement... which seems to be a limitation of sequence. Any way around that one?

Comment: @aw04 - No. SQL Server won't allow you to stuff like that inside a CASE statement, even if it did there is no guarantee about when and how many times it evaluates these expressions. `SELECT CASE WHEN A=B THEN X ELSE Y END FROM T1 JOIN T2 WHERE ...` could have the expression evaluated a different number of times depending on whether it is evaluated before or after the filter and before or after the join for example so it would get very messy allowing things with side effects there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, but if you want something like a counter, maybe you could try to use `row_number()` function:

```
select
    cont -1 as count
from 
    (
    select 
        row_number()  over (order by number) as cont
    from 
        (select 100 as number union all 
         select 100 as number union all 
         select 100 as number) t0
    ) t1
```

Change the from that I've set like example with your table. You will get a counter starting from 0 until the number of rows of your table.